# Will it enough run my asp.net MVC application with 100 MB memory limit in shared hosting server

Tags: hosting

I developed MVC application recently with Asp.net MVC 4 ,Ninject,EF Poco,SQL 2008,Auto Mapper  and hosted in winhost shared hosting server. 
My problem is session expiration. tow or three sustenance request application pool get recycled.

see below support team reply

We host each website in its unique application pool / process. To ensure server stability we recycle the application if any of the following conditions are met:

1) More than 20 minutes of idle time (no http request in 20 minutes)
2) The application uses more than 100 MB memory
3) The application uses more than 70% of CPU resources for more than 3.5 minutes

I checked our server logs and I did found numerous entries where your application pool was recycled because it started to consume over 100 MB of the servers memory. Below are the sample log entries:

TimeGenerated : 9/5/2012 10:03:36 PM
Message : A worker process with process id of '30088' serving application pool 'customerPool_42717' has requested
a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.

TimeGenerated : 9/5/2012 10:02:36 PM
Message : A worker process with process id of '315060' serving application pool 'customerPool_42717' has requeste
d a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.

Unfortunately the log does not tell us what your application is doing that caused it to consume over 100 MB of the servers memory, it only records that it did reach the memory limit.

For the security and performance reason, we do not allow monitoring our server's resources in our shared hosting evironment. You may want to evaluate the amount of memory that your application uses in your development environment and if the requirement is less than 200MB, the easiest solution would be to upgrade your account to a WinHost Max account that will increase the amount of memory available to your worker process to 200MB or to WinHost Ultimate plan that has 300MB of dedicated RAM.

In the event that upgrading your account isn't an option, you may want to consider using SQL Server Session State management since you have a database created and for some more information, please take a moment to review the following WinHost Knowledge Base article:

http://support.winhost.com/KB/a626/how-to-enable-aspnet-sql-server-session-on-your-web.aspx

If you would like the schema installed, please let me know. Please note that sql sessions will not stop your application pool from automatic recycling, but only preserve the sessions when recycling happens.

Can you suggest how to overcome this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok!,clear your machine asp.net root tmp folders:

I step by step this issue answer:
1)Run as Administrator Command Promt
2)`iisreset /stop`
3)Open in explorer 
`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root` or

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root
```

, and remove all temp folders.

4)Back to cmd ,and `iisreset /start`

5) For Web ser CPU problem,or clear your System Drive Clean UP (Your user local temp and `%windir%\Temp` files)

6)If your IIS not worked(Returns the Error code : 509,503,...)

a) `iisreset /stop`
b) `cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root` or

`cd  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`

c) `aspnet_regiis -iru`
d) `iisreset /start`

Try top steps.

Comment: I hosted in shared hosting environmental and I don't have administrative rights.

Comment: As I know on shared hosting environment your cant use session, as it will make the instability on the server, instead of you can use cookies on your code or you can use SQL server session. And also you may check your application that you're running. I believe it will impact to server performance if you consume more than 100 MB.